# Trouble with loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

I am still pretty new to programming in R, and loops always seem to trip me up. What I am trying to do is compare my capacity to demand, and take the smaller of the two values to calculate profit. In the below example in the 6th position capacity is 55,000 but demand is 56,074.44 so I can only produce my capacity.

Current code:

```
UnitCost <- 3.70
Capacity <- c(30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000)

Profit <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Capacity)) {
  Demand <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 50000, sd = 12000)
  Revenue[i] <- min(Demand, Capacity[i]) * UnitCost
  Profit[i] <- sum(Revenue[i])
}
demand
Profit
```

Output:

```
> Demand
[1] 56074.44
> Profit
[1] 111000.0 129500.0 148000.0 166500.0 185000.0 118181.7 207475.4
```

Output Needed:

```
> Demand
[1] 56074.44
> Profit
[1] 111000.0 129500.0 148000.0 166500.0 185000.0 203500.0 207475.4
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `rnorm` to generate random numbers - I'm not aware if you `set.seed` - if not, you should get different results and outcomes for `Profit` every time you run this, especially for the last few in `Capacity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would use `sapply` instead of the `for` loop, as follows:

```
sapply(Capacity, function(cap){
  sum(min(demand, cap) * UnitCost)
})
```

This would give you the following output for the `demand` indicated in your question:

```
# 111000.0 129500.0 148000.0 166500.0 185000.0 203500.0 207475.4
```

**EDIT:** To apply this to multiple-year demands, you may do the following:

```
num.years <- 1:5
sums <- data.frame(t(sapply(num.years, function(i){
  set.seed(i-1)
  demand <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = 50000, sd = 12000)
  sapply(Capacity, function(cap){
    sum(min(demand, cap) * UnitCost)
  })
})))
row.names(sums) <-  paste0("Year_", num.years)
colnames(sums) <-  Capacity
sums
```

This will give you the following output:

```
#          30000   35000     40000     45000     50000     55000     60000
# Year_1  111000  129500  148000.0  166500.0  185000.0  203500.0  222000.0
# Year_2  111000  129500  148000.0  166500.0  180392.6  180392.6  180392.6
# Year_3  111000  129500  148000.0  160263.8  160263.8  160263.8  160263.8
# Year_4  111000  129500  148000.0  166500.0  185000.0  203500.0  222000.0
# Year_5  111000  129500  145352.7  145352.7  145352.7  145352.7  145352.7
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was helpful and lets me determine the best option for a single year demand. Can you use the sapply method in a for loop? Say I have to simulate 5 years with of demand using the rnorm method and then sum the total for each plant capacity over the 5 years to see which is highest.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. You can even have two nested `sapply` (one inside another). Have a look at my updated answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided is not complete. I have a couple of questions -

- Is your demand a constant? Why are you assigning a value of to it the loop?
- What is 'd' in the line where you assigning the value of Revenue?

I assume 'd' is the demand and I re-wrote your code, which seems to give the desired output.

```
UnitCost <- 3.70
Capacity <- c(30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000)
demand <- 56074.44

Profit <- c()
Revenue <- c()

for (i in 1:length(Capacity)) {
    Revenue[i] <- min(demand, Capacity[i]) * UnitCost
    Profit[i] <- sum(Revenue[i])
}

demand
Profit
```

Output -

```
demand
[1] 56074.44
Profit
[1] 111000.0 129500.0 148000.0 166500.0 185000.0 203500.0 207475.4
```

Comment: Thanks...so I have a couple questions. My demand is supposed to be determined randomly since this is a part of a larger Monte Carlo simulation. If I use my original formula for demand and pull it out of the loop it seems to work fine, but I guess I don't know why that is.

Comment: Also, if I pull it out of my loop, then I am not able to run a simulation 1,000 times to get different demand amounts each time.

Comment: Since your `Demand` is a randomly generated variable, there's no way of getting a "fixed" output. The condition for `Revenue` will produce a different result, which in turn affects `Profit`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need `for` loop for `*apply` functions, and `pmin` can help you to get the desired output

```
Demand <- rnorm(length(Capacity),mean = 50000, sd = 12000)
Profit <- pmin(Capacity,demand) * UnitCost
```

such that

```
> Profit
[1] 111000.0 129500.0 148000.0 166500.0 185000.0 203500.0 207475.4
```